HUB table creation in DV SCD type2
Looking for recommendations for HUB table creation with multiple business key.
which one is advisable to create single HUB table like below?For e.g.
 create table h_x
(
hkey,  --> sha2(a_bkey,256)
load_dt,
rec_src_cd,
a_bkey,
b_bkey,
c_bkey

)
or 

create table h_x
( hkey, → sha2(a_bkey+‘-’+b_bkey+‘-’+c_bkey,256)
load_dt,
rec_src_cd,
a_bkey+‘-’+b_bkey+‘-’+c_bkey as bkey

)


What is exactly to be advised about? Apart from first example missing b and c business key; second contains business key concatenation. If you intend to group two HUB tables together and they have different business keys, then concatenation could help
